# Why is Ubuntu 14.04 running slow on my Asus Zenbook UX302 LG? + brightness issue

Tags: 14.04, brightness, asus

It's a fresh install alongside Windows 8.1. I have already tried to modify the grub file by adding acpi=off but it doesn't speed up things.

The machine has an i7-4500U processor, 8 GB of RAM and nVidia 730M dedicated graphics card and runs Windows smoothly.

Moreover, I am also unable to adjust the brightness level of the display, neither by Fn keys nor by going to the system settings menu, since the brightness adjusting bar does not appear on the screen. It is constantly stuck at max level. I have tried to place acpi_backlight=vendor and other recommendations but they don't solve the issue.

My grub file contains the nomodeset option. Otherwise, ubuntu boots to a black screen on my machine.

I would kindly appreciate any suggestions for fixing these problems. One final note: I'm a novice in what Linux is concerned.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

mbs

Comment: It will be easier if you ask the two questions separately.  When you indicate that Ubuntu is slow on your system, what do you mean my that?

Comment: I will split them. By slow I mean lag for almost any activity, from maximizing/minimizing windows, typing text, opening apps, etc

Comment: Is your system using the hardware for open gl?  You can check by typing `glxinfo | grep renderer`  You do not want to see something about llvmpipes.  You may need to `apt-get install mesa-utils` first.

Answer (score 0):

press your windows key and type `drivers` then click on the `additional drivers` icon and let it search for a while.
once its loaded, see if you're using the nouveau display drivers or nvidia ones.
You should make it use the nvidia binary driver, and logout, sign in again.

see if this changes anything.

Comment: tried doing that, selected the nvidia proprietary tested and now i log in and can just see my desktop background

Comment: can you try this guide to reinstall unity? http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: will try to do so and come back afterwards

Comment: The slowness you're experiencing is fps lag from the default nouveau driver. So to fix that is updating your graphics driver, but that seems to destroy your unity. How far are you on following the steps i gave you